# list all pythagorean triplets in java

Tags: java, methods, return, pythagorean

I need to find all pythagorean triples (a^2+b^2=c^2) with values of A and B less than 100. My codes don't give me the correct output. Could anyone tell me what went wrong with my codes and write the correct codes instead?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int sum = 0;

    for (int num1 = 1; num1 <= 100; num1++) {
        for (int num2 = 1; num2 < 100; num2++) {
            if (PerfectSquare(num1, num2, sum)) {
                System.out.println(num1 + " " + num2);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static boolean PerfectSquare(int number1, int number2, int sum) {

    int square1;
    int square2;
    double root;
    int sum1;

    number1 = (int) ((99 - 1 + 1) * Math.random() + 1);
    number2 = (int) ((99 - 1 + 1) * Math.random() + 1);

    square1 = (int) Math.pow(number1, 2.0);
    square2 = (int) Math.pow(number2, 2.0);
    sum = square1 + square2;
    root = Math.sqrt(sum);
    sum1 = (int) Math.pow(root, 2.0);

    if (!(sum == sum1)) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: For one thing, you are overwriting your `number1` and `number2` parameters with random numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting your `number1` and `number2` parameters with random numbers:

```
number1 = (int) ((99 - 1 + 1 ) * Math.random() + 1);
number2 = (int) ((99 - 1 + 1 ) * Math.random() + 1);
```

You may as well not be passing in any values at all into the method  if you do this. Remove these lines.

Also, you need to round your square root to an integer:

```
root = (int) Math.sqrt(sum);
```

since otherwise you will end up with the same number when you square it again.

---

Other points not related to correctness:

- You can square integers without needing to cast by multiplying them with themselves:

  ```
  square1 = number1 * number1;
  ```
- This:

  ```
  if (! (sum==sum1) ) {
  ```

  is more easily written as

  ```
  if (sum != sum1) {
  ```
- Your `sum` method parameter is unnecessary. Declare it as a local variable.
- You don't need to loop over all pairs of `num1` and `num2`, since if `(num1, num2)` are the opposite and adjacent sides of a Pythagorean triple, then `(num2, num1)` clearly are too (similarly if `num1` and `num2` aren't, then `num2` and `num1` aren't either). As such, you can check fewer combinations using:

  ```
  for (int num1 = 1; num1 <= 100 ; num1++) {
    for (int num2 =1; num2 <num1; num2++) {
  ```

Comment: I finally got it. Thanks!